# How can I use special characters in an XSL transformation?

Tags: xml, templates, xslt

I'm working on a tool for generating source code that follows a certain template. I'm trying to use an XML file for storing the values such as strings and method names and an XSL transformation to generate the code.
The problem is that the source code contains the characters '>' and '<'. I read that by writing text in a  tag I could use character entities (< or >) and they would be converted in the result but I would want to use the original characters in the XSL transformation directly and keep as much of the original source code as possible in its original state. Is there any way I could do that in xslt?
I'm also willing to try other ways of generating code as long as the solution allows easy insertion of values.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If your desired output is XML, then it doesn't matter the special character encoding as long as the output **consumer** can handle XML documents. Semanticly speaking, there is no diference between `>` and `&gt;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, this is not an XSLT question,

**Use**: **[CDATA](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-cdsection)** as in the following example:

```
<ProgramFragment>
 <![CDATA[if(x <> y) {z}]]>
</ProgramFragment>
```

**However, never put markup** (if your programming language is XML-based, such as XSLT) **inside a CDATA section** -- this is *evil* as it destroys the structure and smashes it into a flat and unusable string.

Answer (score 0):

You can put code in `CDATA` sections:

```
<![CDATA[
 code with >, <, & here
]]>
```